# How to search in multiple .php files?

Tags: php, search

I have around 100 .php files in one directory and I'm looking for one small function, what's the fastest way to search trough all contents of these files?

[edit]

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate/NuSphere PhpED.

Comment: If you have Linux or Mac - you can use [`grep`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html). If you have windows, you could use [wingrep](http://www.wingrep.com/). Some editors also have a 'Find text in directories' function, but it really depends on what you're using.

Comment: [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin.html)

Comment: refer this project: https://github.com/skfaisal93/AnyWhereInFiles

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
<?php
function getFilesWith($folder, $searchFor, $extension = 'php') {

    if($folder) {
        $foundArray = array();
        // GRAB ALL FILENAMES WITH SUPPLIED EXTENSION
        foreach(glob($folder . sprintf("*.%s", $extension)) as $file) {
            $contents = file_get_contents($file);

            if(strpos($contents, $searchFor) !== false) {
                $foundArray[] = $file;
            }
        }

        if(count($foundArray)) {
            return $foundArray;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$matched_files = getFilesWith('path/to/folder', 'Looking for this');
?>
```

Comment: I mean, I applaud the effort, but this is overkill!

Comment: @birryree on shared hosting with limited access this is the only way to be sure it will work

Comment: I agree...searching with code is required if we only have FTP access and don't want to download all the files......

Answer (score 6):

Use your php editors "find in files" function.

Invaluable.

**edit** [PHPNuSphere](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_editor_find_text.htm) totally supports this. you need to learn some google fu brother.

<strike>If your editor doesn't have this, you  need to switch ASAP.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+editor</strike>

[image: Find in files in Visual Studio]

[image: Find in files in Notepad++]

Comment: I'm using NuSphere PhpED, I'm not sure if it has this function.

Comment: In fact I have never dreamed of this function in my PHP editor, was thinking about totally different solution, like cmd-related stuff or a php function. And all I needed was just two clicks away ;/ Thank you so much!

Comment: I could never learn a new codebase without find in files ;) good luck!

Answer (score 4):

Install cgywin - then you can use grep!

Comment: that was going to be my answer! +1

Answer (score 1):

```
function search_in_dir( $dir, $str )
{
    $files = glob( "{$dir}/*.php" );
    foreach( $files as $k => $file )
    {
        $source = file_get_contents( $file );
        if( strpos( $source, $str ) === false )
        {
            unset( $files[$k] );
        }
    }
    return array_filter( $files );
}
$files = search_in_dir( 'dir/files', 'my string' );
```

Answer (score 0):

For Window I would install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and use find or grep, but failing that

- Install total commander, use Alt + F7 to search recursively. There's also a replace in multiple files option - http://www.ghisler.com
  You will wonder how you ever navigated your system without it
- using [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v5.9.3.html) you can open all files and do a normal text search just check the box 'search in all open files'

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code

```
<?php
$folder = 'folder';
echo '<p><b>We Find</b> in <span style="color:red">'. __DIR__ .'</span></p> ';

foreach (glob("$folder/*.php") as $filename) {

$file = file_get_contents($filename);

if( strpos( $file, 'text' ) === false ){
    echo '<span style="color:red">not found: </span>';
}else{
    echo '<span style="color:blue">found: </span>';
}

echo $filename.'<br>';

if (file_put_contents($filename, preg_replace("/text/", "new text", $file))) {

} else {
    echo "not found :(";
}
}
```

Create a folder in the path to your code
Put your files in that folder
The files containing your text are displayed in blue. Then the texts will be replaced